# PHP get users latest twitter feed using twitter Oauth tools (consumer key , access token , consumer secret , access secret)

Tags: php, oauth, twitter, tweets

I need to get the twitter latest feed of the user. i used

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?oauth_token=ecwmW3pMB8euREHVljdySRexys6c6XYangqEANY&screen_name=twitter_name&count=1
```

but i get "Rate limit exceeded" cliente could not make 150 request per hour.

I used twitter Oauth request using consumer key, consumer secret , access token and access secret and the code as follows

```
$oauth_consumer_key="Vqlj7vd9yHo5MZPnWGf3w";
$oauth_nonce="af00a3a26b15ec0178ce0342acc9b392";
$oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1";
$oauth_timestamp="1341408794";
$oauth_token="620811780-30jD4XHWFvp15RcjmxHkLLicFlvMDuNaWp6fKjia";
$oauth_version="1.0";
$oauth_signature=rawurldecode("N6L4VJLJjY%2BPKxoelttqe2GOPAw%3D");

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?";
$url .= "screen_name=twitter_name";
$url .= "&oauth_consumer_key=".$oauth_consumer_key."";
$url .= "&oauth_token=".$oauth_token."";
$url .= "&oauth_nonce=".$oauth_nonce."";
$url .= "&oauth_signature_method=".$oauth_signature_method."";
$url .= "&oauth_timestamp=".$oauth_timestamp."";
$url .= "&oauth_version=1.0";
$url .= "&oauth_signature=".$oauth_signature."";
$url .= "&count=1";
$url .= "&include_rts=true";
$url .= "include_entities=true";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: api.twitter.com'));
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($json);
```

still i get the rate limit exceeded error.

could any one help me get twitter latest feed using Oauth.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this an issue that it will always return 'rate limit exceeded error' or are you not waiting before trying again?

Comment: Yes "the rate limit exceeded" is the error am getting.Initially am not used Oauth tech to get feeds, it works fine. when the request get exceeded i get '"Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour."'
So i used twitter Oauth to increase the request rate up to 350 per hour.After using the script am getting same error "Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour."...Kindly advise me how to use twitter oauth to get latest tweet.

Answer (score 0):

From experience Twitter OAuth is hit and miss if you try to handle negotiations yourself. I tried for several weeks to achieve this but kept having errors like 'Rate limit exceeded' and 'Invalid OAuth Key'. I checked out a library and within the same hour I could get statuses, set statuses, send tweets with and without pics etc..

Here's what I'm using now, test it out. It's lightweight and easy to use.

https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth/